# Zip two lists based on specific condition in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have two defined case classes and two lists like the following code.

```scala
case class Person(name: String, company: String, rank: Int, id: Long)

case class Employee(company: String, rank: Int, id: Long)
```

```scala
val persons = List(Person("Tom", "CompanyA", 1, null), Person("Jenny", "CompanyB", 1, null), Person("James", "CompanyA", 2, null))

val employees = List(Employee("CompanyA", 1, 1001), Employee("CompanyB", 1, 1002), Employee("CompanyA", 2, 1003))
```

since the combination of `company` and `rank` is unique, I want to use the information in `employees` so that I can combine the two lists into the following one (A list of Person with id fulfilled).

```scala
[Person("Tom", "CompanyA", 1, 1001), Person("Jenny", "CompanyB", 1, 1002), Person("James", "CompanyA", 2, 1003)]
```

I tried to implement it as this:

```scala
zipBasedOnCondition(persons, employees, (person, employee) => person.name == employee.name && person.rank === employee.rank)
```

However, I failed to come up with a solution to implement the  `zipBasedOnCondition` function

Is there any solution to combine the two lists?

Comment: Can you share the output what exactly do you want?

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal A list of `Person` with `id` fulfilled: `[Person("Tom", "CompanyA", 1, 1001), Person("Jenny", "CompanyB", 1, 1002), Person("James", "CompanyA", 2, 1003)]`

Comment: I wouldn't call this a `zip` use case. More like `for { a <- persons; b <- employees; if condition } yield (a, b)`.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Yep, I don't expect it to be mapped into tuples. I should come up with a better term.

Comment: Do you want persons that don't have a corresponding employee to be included in the result?

Comment: @senjin.hajrulahovic Yes, though its id won't be fulfilled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by:

```scala
for {
  person <- persons
  employee <- employees
  if person.name == employee.name && person.rank === employee.rank
} yield person.copy(id = employee.id)
```

It has time complexity of O(persons.size*employees.size) but since `List` has no guarantees about things inside being sorted (and especially, being sorted by the things you want to compare against) you cannot optimize it anymore.

If you want, you could modify it so that it would took the first one of possible pairs, though how is beyond the scope of "zip with condition".

Answer (score 0):

I'm still thinking of better solutions... but this should work:

```
def f(c: String): Option[Employee] = employees.filter(_.company == c).headOption

for {
  p <- persons
  e <- f(p.company)
} yield {
  p.copy(id = e.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a pretty generic approach:

```
def zipBasedOnCondition[A, B, C](as: List[A], bs: List[B], pred: (A, B) => Boolean, f: (A, B) => C): List[C] = {
    as.map(a => f(a, bs.filter(b => pred(a, b)).head))
}
```

then you could call it like this:

```
zipBasedOnCondition[Person, Employee, Person](persons, employees, (p, e) => p.name == e.name && p.rank == e.rank, (a, b) => a.copy(id = b.id))
```

The implementation of `zipBasedOnCondition` would need improvement since it assumes that for every person object there is a corresponding employee object.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Though the combination is unique, the corresponding object may be absent.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing id fied as mandatory field in Person class and providing null value in person list that will give error.
First let's correct your Person class.

```
 case class Person(name: String, company: String, rank: Int, id: Long = 0)
```

Now, Solution to your question.

```
 def combineList( list1: List[Person], list2: List[Employee]): List[(Person)] = {
  (for{
   a <- list1
   b <- list2
   if (a.company == b.company && a.rank == b.rank)
  } yield (a.copy(id = b.id)))
 }
```

**Output**

```
List(Person(Tom,CompanyA,1,1001), Person(Jenny,CompanyB,1,1002), Person(James,CompanyA,2,1003))
```